# Compile-time information lost with conversion to object, cannot cast to generic interface<T>

Tags: c#

I have a class implementing a concrete typed version of a generic interface. I have found that if I pass an object in to my function (even though it might be the correct object) at compile time it is still considered an object and thus failing at runtime with the error:

`Unable to cast object of type 'TestEventHandler' to type 'IDomainEventHandler '1[System.Object]'.`

I am deserializing messages from a bus (which products objects, which should have an associated `DomainEventHandler<of_deserialized_type>` associated with the message.

In summary, the problem I believe is `IDomainEventHandler<T>` not casting from `` `IDomainEventHandler<object> ``, I would appreciate guidance on how best to solve this issue and still maintain the generic `IDomainEventHandler<T>` interface even with objects being passed in to `Publish()`.

```
[TestClass]
public class InternalMessageHandlerTests
{
    class TestEvent
    {
    }

    class TestEventHandler : IDomainEventHandler<TestEvent>
    {
        public void HandleEvent(TestEvent domainEvent)
        {
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        TestEvent testEvent = new TestEvent();
        object testEventAsObject = testEvent; // compile time type information lost 
        Publish(testEvent); // this is OK :)
        Publish(testEventAsObject); // this fails :(

    }

    public void Publish<T>(T eventToPublish) where T : class
    {
        var handlerInstance = new TestEventHandler();
        IDomainEventHandler<T> converted = (IDomainEventHandler<T>)handlerInstance;
        converted.HandleEvent(eventToPublish);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931278/644812)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, it is not possible to support a fully-generic interface without reflection. And reflection is a pretty bad idea for such a simple case.

My normal approach for these situations is `IDomainEventHandler`, then `DomainEventHandlerBase<T> : IDomainEventHandler` so that inheriting classes get all advantage of generics, but outside interface can accept objects.

Obviously it is not statically safe, but as I said it is not possible to be statically safe here. As soon as you assigned your instance to `object testEventAsObject`, you made it possible for this variable to contain anything from the compiler point of view (`string`, `int`, anything).

For the things like service bus where you have to select the right handler, it would look like this:

```
public interface IDomainEventHandler {
    void HandleEvent(object domainEvent);
    bool CanHandleEvent(object domainEvent);
}

public abstract class DomainEventHandlerBase<T> : IDomainEventHandler {
    public abstract void HandleEvent(T domainEvent);
    public abstract bool CanHandleEvent(T domainEvent);

    void IDomainEventHandler.HandleEvent(object domainEvent) {
        return HandleEvent((T)domainEvent);
    }

    bool IDomainEventHandler.CanHandleEvent(object domainEvent) {            
        return (domainEvent is T) && CanHandleEvent((T)domainEvent);
    }
}
```

I has written that directly (without checking in VS) so mistakes are possible.

After that when you receive a message just select

```
handlers.First(h => h.CanHandleEvent(domainEvent))
```

Comment: Hi Andrey so the base class would do the type casting to the correct event type? If you could drop an example when you have time would be appreciated

Comment: @g18c Sure, added an example (sorry for any possible mistakes).

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert `TestEventHandler` to `IDomainEventHandler<object>` since this is not safe. If it were allowed you could do:

```
IDomainEventHandler<object> converted = (IDomainEventHandler<object>)new TestEventHandler();
converted.HandleEvent("dsfs");
```

which is invalid since `TestEventHandler` requires its argument to `HandleEvent` to be `TestEvent`.

You could invoke `Publish` using reflection:

```
TestEvent testEvent = new TestEvent();
object testEventAsObject = testEvent;
var publishMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("Publish").MakeGenericMethod(testEventAsObject.GetType());
publishMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { testEventAsObject });
```

Comment: Thanks Lee is reflection significantly slower than native calls? I dont want to prematurely optimise but since this is bus messaging a fair amount of messages will be passing through each second

Comment: @g18c - Yes reflection is quite a bit slower than making direct calls, so this could be a problem if you have a lot of messages - I thought from your example this was just test code. If this approach is too slow, you could define a non-generic `IDomainEventHandler` to handle `object` messages and cast to the expected message type in the handler. Then you would just need to test the handler mapping.

Comment: Just to update I have continued to use my generic definition of known compile time type T for internal messaging and events, these would be lighting fast as types were known correctly. For object types coming in from the bus, i invoked via reflection as per your code and whilst at first i was thinking about speed in reality since messages come in from the network bus (i.e. slow) reflection is still many magnitudes faster than the bus. So in the end i ended up with the best of both worlds with speed (for in process messaging) and flexibility when dispatching (with the slower bus)! :)