# C# Generics / ICommandHandler/ICommand design

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I've got to design a Command/CommandHandler module and am struggling with the details of the design.

I've created an (empty) interface:

```
public interface ICommand {}
```

which is implemented by various commands,

e.g.

```
public interface TestCommand : ICommand {}
```

One (or more) CommandHandlers can register for a specific implementation of `ICommand`. To avoid constant casting I've built an interface:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand>
       where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

So far so good...the command dispatching system is the troubling stuff: The command handlers should be injected by Autofac (or any other DI system), e.g.:

```
public CommandDispatcher (IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand>> commandHandlers)
```

As you can see this is not possible. `ICommandHandler<CommandType1>` and `ICommandHandler<CommandType2>` are not derived from `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` and can therefore not be put into the same IEnumerable.

Any suggestions how to design this in a non-problematic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would resolve them just before invoking them. For example, in Autofac

```
class CommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly Autofac.IComponentContext context; // inject this

    public void Dispatch<TCommand>(TCommand command)
    {
        var handlers = context.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>>();
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle(command);
        }
    }

    public void ReflectionDispatch(ICommand command)
    {
        Action<CommandDispatcher, ICommand> action = BuildAction(command.GetType());
        // see link below for an idea of how to implement BuildAction

        action(this, command);
    }
}
```

If you need to change the method signature to `Dispatch(ICommand command)`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931278/644812). You should be able to adapt this to your situation.

Comment: It looks like a very bad practice to me to inject the container everywhere. Shouldn't this happen only on the top level?

Comment: You don't inject the container "everywhere", only into certain pieces of infrastructure code. As long as a very small percentage of your code references the container, it is fine. Some people would recommend defining `ICommandDispatcher` and then only creating an `AutofacCommandDispatcher` at the composition root, but I think that is unnecessary indirection - it's the same amount of work if you switch DI containers; the only advantage would be if you want no reference to the Autofac DLL in a "business logic" assembly.

Comment: We've switched to this solution to avoid the unwanted reference + we've used the reflection idea of your linked post. Thanks.